# IEEE citation style is not coming with report class

Tags: ieeetran, multiple-citations

More than 2 citations are coming like this [1-3]. But I want them as [1]-[3].
2 Consecutive citations are coming like this [2, 4], but I want them as [2], [4].

I am using Tex Studio. When I use `IEEEtran` class, citations comes as [1]-[3]. But I am trying to get this style in my thesis which is written with `report` class. An executable MWE is provided here. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite} % citation 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES} 

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
    \begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{5pt} %Controls the spacing between two references.
        \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
    }
    {
    \end{oldthebibliography}
}


\begin{document}

More than 2 citations are coming like this \cite{Shafiei2017, Martins2017, JohnCrothers2017}. But I want them as [1]-[3]. 2 Consecutive citations are coming like this \cite{Wajda2017,Martins2017}, but I want them as [2], [4].


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Physics}
    
\end{document}
```

Citation entries are

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.19.4
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@article{Wajda2017,
author = {Wajda, Tadeusz},
doi = {10.5539/apr.v9n6p67},
issn = {1916-9639},
journal = {Applied Physics Research},
number = {6},
pages = {67},
title = {{Dilation of Time Dilation}},
volume = {9},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Shafiei2017,
author = {Shafiei, Ziaedin},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/miais/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Shafiei - 2017 - Is Time Dilation a scientific theory.pdf:pdf},
number = {October},
title = {{Is Time Dilation a scientific theory ?}},
year = {2017}
}
@article{JohnCrothers2017,
author = {{John Crothers}, Stephen},
doi = {10.11648/j.ajmp.20170603.12},
issn = {2326-8867},
journal = {American Journal of Modern Physics},
number = {3},
pages = {43},
title = {{On the Logical Inconsistency of the Special Theory of Relativity}},
volume = {6},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Tartaglia2017,
author = {Tartaglia, Angelo and Lucchesi, David and Ruggiero, Matteo Luca and Valko, Pavol},
doi = {10.1109/MetroAeroSpace.2017.7999548},
isbn = {9781509042340},
journal = {4th IEEE International Workshop on Metrology for AeroSpace, MetroAeroSpace 2017 - Proceedings},
pages = {108--113},
title = {{LAGRANGE: An experiment for testing general relativity in the inner solar system}},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Martins2017,
author = {Martins, P. and Alves, L. Nero and Mendes, J. C.},
doi = {10.1109/ECCTD.2017.8093266},
isbn = {9781538639740},
journal = {2017 European Conference on Circuit Theory and Design, ECCTD 2017},
keywords = {Memristive systems,Memristors,Special Relativity (SR),State-space},
pages = {1--4},
title = {{On the dynamics of accelerated observers in Special Relativity}},
year = {2017}
}
```

Comment: The package `cite` offers the option to customize these. Change `\citeform` or `\citepunct`.

Comment: Will You please elaborate, when I tried using `citeform` it's changing the citation format. It's not coming in IEEE format anymore

Comment: `\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}` after using this in the preamble I get the following result : [[1]-[3]]. Now how to remove this extra square bracket

Comment: Adding these `\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}
\renewcommand\citeleft{}
\renewcommand\citeright{}` in the preamble solves my problem. But I don't know If it's the efficient way to do this

Comment: Or `\def\citepunct{], [}` and `\def\citedash{]--[}`.

Comment: Thanks, I think Your suggested one is better. I will follow this one